# Parts of font in Google ReCaptcha not visible

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, recaptcha

I've successfully implemented Googles ReCaptcha to my webpage.
Sometimes it ocurrs, that the user hast to select a few images, e.g. "Select all Images displaying Trains". Now the problem is, that for me (Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), it works in Firefox) doesnt display the "Trains". Heres a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

So anyone who doesnt know how to use the developer tools of chrome to find out what exactly he has to select will be lost here.

I use a custom font on my webpage, If that causes the problem, but It shouldn't, because the font is by google too, it wouldn't be very wise of google to let their own fonts mess up their ReCaptcha.

Solution anyone?

Comment: The key words, such as "Trains" in your example, are wrapped in a `<strong>` tag. Are you styling `<strong>` tags in your CSS? Or perhaps your custom font doesn't have a bold version available?

Comment: If i use `<strong>` tags in my normal content it works with the same font so I assume that the problem is elsewhere :/